Refreshing Global DB Connection Using STS Token in NestJS
When the initial connection to the RDS is made, it works fine, but after the token expires, the application encounters a PAM authentication error. I need a solution to refresh the global database connection with a new STS token at regular intervals. I prefer not to manage this at each service and repository level but to have a global refresh mechanism.
Here is my current implementation:
app.module.ts
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [DatabaseModule],
  inject: [DbService],
  useFactory: async (dbService: DbService) => {
    const config = await dbService.getDataSource();
    return config.options;
  },
  extraProviders: [DbService],
}),

db.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class DbService {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    @InjectDataSource() private dataSource: DataSource,
  ) {
    this.initDataSource();
  }

  private async initDataSource() {
    const config = await getDatabaseConfig(this.authService);
    this.dataSource = new DataSource(config);
    await this.dataSource.initialize();
  }

  private async refreshTokenAndReconnect() {
    if (this.dataSource?.isInitialized) {
      await this.dataSource.destroy();
    }

    const config = await getDatabaseConfig(this.authService);
    this.dataSource.setOptions(config);
    await this.dataSource.initialize();
  }

  @Cron('0 */20 * * * *')
  async handleTokenRefresh() {
    await this.refreshTokenAndReconnect();
  }

  public async getDataSource(): Promise<DataSource> {
    if (!this.dataSource || !this.dataSource?.options) {
      await this.refreshTokenAndReconnect();
    }
    return this.dataSource;
  }
}

database.config.ts
const configService = new ConfigService();
export async function getDatabaseConfig(
  authService: AuthService,
): Promise<DataSourceOptions> {
  const authToken = await authService.generateAuthToken();
  console.log(authToken);

  return {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
    password: authToken,
    database: configService.get('DB_NAME'),
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    extra: {
      poolSize: 10,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
    entities: [`${__dirname}/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}`],
    synchronize: false
  };
}

auth.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor() {}

  // Method to generate the STS token
  async generateAuthToken() {
    const dbEndpoint = process.env.DB_HOST;
    const dbUser = process.env.DB_USER;
    const dbPort = +process.env.DB_PORT;
    const dbRegion = process.env.AWS_REGION;
    try {
      const signer = new Signer({
        hostname: dbEndpoint,
        port: dbPort,
        username: dbUser,
        region: dbRegion,
      });
      console.log(signer);

      const token = await signer.getAuthToken();
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new NotFoundError(error);
    }
  }
}

How can I ensure that my NestJS application automatically refreshes the RDS connection globally when the STS token expires, without requiring a full refactor or significant changes at each service or repository level?
